# Why are Delta baryons called "Delta isobars"?

Tags: terminology, quantum-chromodynamics, isospin-symmetry, baryons

A [lot of people](https://arxiv.org/search/?query=delta%20isobar&searchtype=all&abstracts=show&order=-announced_date_first&size=50) seem to call the $\Delta$ baryon "Delta isobar", however there is no mention of "isobar" on its [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_baryon) page. Am I missing something? Why do people use the term "Delta isobar"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nuclear physics, an isobar is a set of nuclei with the same mass number, and you can move within an isobar by changing protons to neutrons. There is an analogous notion in particle physics called "isotopic spin", or more simply isospin, which moves between hadrons of similar mass by changing up quarks to down quarks.

[Wikipedia claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) that in nuclear physics, they call isospin "isobaric spin", so under that nomenclature, the $\Delta$ baryons form an isobar. (Similarly, the proton and neutron form an isobar, along with excited quadruplets $\Delta^*$ or doublets $N^*$.)

It seems the term "isobar" can only be applied for baryons made of only up and down quarks. In high energy physics, we don't have a special name for these baryons, because we're usually working at energies well above what you need to produce several more kinds of quarks, but if you restrict to low energy reactions it could be a useful category.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! So for any baryon $B$ with isospin $I$, the $2I+1$ baryons in this multiplet are collectively called $B$-isobars..?

Comment: @ersbygre1 Yes; for example, the nucleon $N$ is a doublet ($I=\frac{1}{2}$) isobar, consisting of the proton and the neutron.